# Is there a programmatic way to check whether specific CSS rules are valid or respected by the browser, or it is discarded / less specific?

Tags: javascript, css, reflection

I am looking for a way in JS to inspect or check current state of CSS rules dynamically at runtime (using browser's reflection feature, possibly) instead of only relying for browser developer's tool to see which rules are "overriden" or filtered. To think an analogy in procedural languages, there's normally a way to check the status or result of each instruction or function that we call (e.g true/false).

```
.mybutton#submit {
  color: red;
}
.mybutton {
  color: blue;
}
```

In other words, I am asking if there is an easy way to implement hypothethical is_valid below.

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;
is_valid(rules[0]); //True
is_valid(rules[1]); //False
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, your hypothetical `is_valid()` function would at need a document too: otherwise it's impossibly to know if any of the selectors even match anything. In your example, for instance, you can only know if the second rule is unnecessary by checking for a `.mybutton` who isn't also `#submit`.

Comment: Yes. That is why I note runtime/dynamic evaluation.